# Align part of formula

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I would like to align to the left the first part of a formula inside a set. I tried using align, but it does not work well with the big paranthesis. 
Here is my code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
$\forall U\subset_d \Spec A,$
$$\mathcal{O}(U)=\left\{s:U\rightarrow\bigsqcup_{p\in U}A_p \mid  
\begin{matrix}  
\forall p\in U, s(p)\in A_p\\ 
\forall p\in U, \exists V\in\mathcal{V}(p), V\subset U, \exists a,f\in A, \text{ astfel \^inc\^at } \forall q\in V, f\notin q, s(q)=\frac{a}{f} \text{ \^in }A_q
\end{matrix}
\right\}$$
\end{document}`
```

And here is a picture of what I am trying to accomplish [image]:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}

\begin{document}

$\forall U\subset_d \Spec A$,
\[
\mathcal{O}(U)=
\biggl\{s\colon U\rightarrow\bigsqcup_{p\in U}A_p
\;\bigg|\;
\begin{aligned}
&\forall p\in U, s(p)\in A_p\\
&\forall p\in U, \exists V\in\mathcal{V}(p), V\subset U, \exists a,f\in A,
  \text{ astfel \^inc\^at } \forall q\in V, f\notin q, s(q)=\tfrac{a}{f} \text{ \^in }A_q
\end{aligned}
\biggr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Some notes.

1. Punctuation should go after inline formulas
2. `\left`\and `\right` give too big delimiters in this case
3. `$$` should be never used in LaTeX
4. `\tfrac` is used not to make a big fraction

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask why do you say that $$ should not be used in LaTeX?

Comment: @Iulia See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)